# Mobile number service provider in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any API or gem that gives mobile number service provider name? I just want to display service provider name when user enters his mobile number.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any gem available that does this. I even had trouble finding equivalent stuff in other languages.

The other problem I think you would run into is, now that numbers can be easily ported from one carrier to another, you have a lot less of a guarantee on accuracy, even if you found a service to interact with. I've done searches on my old mobile number, and it shows as being registered to the carrier I originally signed up with, even though I've moved that number to multiple other networks by now.

Answer (score 0):

Having some experience with this myself (from affiliate marketing), if there was an open API for this, it would be highly popular

As it stands, there are a lot of premium services which allow you to gain this information. Some of the biggest include:

- [Whitepages](http://whitepages.com)
- [PeopleSearchAffiliates](http://www.peoplesearchaffiliates.com/)
- [Intelius](http://www.intelius.com/reverse-phone-lookup.html)
- [Free Cell Phone Tracer](http://freephonetracer.com)

I actually made a simple script to get the carrier data from one of these services, and use the data to create an interactive map, which was really successful. I've lost the script now, but  it was about finding carrier data from a specific source (I've forgotten which), and appending it with JS

The reason why this is a premium-centric market is because it takes a lot to get the information you need to make the service viable, hence why "free" API's aren't existent